# Program that shows the two previous numbers in a txt file

Tags: c++

I have a program that gets a number from the user, finds it in a text file and shows the number in the next line. I want that program to also show the two numbers in the previous two lines.

**Examples**

> If the number is `1.29`:

The output should be:

> `next number is: 9  and previous numbers are 6 and 08`
>
> `next number is: 4.33  and previous numbers are 1 and 1.73`
>
> `next number is: 7  and previous numbers are 4 and 73`

The `file.txt` content is:

```
79
08
08
6
1.29
9
87
57
098
1.73
1
1.29
4.33
76
73
4
1.29
7
```

This is what I have so far:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <term.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int x = 0;
  int tt = 0;
  int jj = 0;
  float number;
  char t = '\0';
  int temp = 0;
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("file.txt");
  if (!inFile) {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    exit(1); // terminate with error
  }
  cout << "Please enter a number: ";
  cin >> number;
  {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("file.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
      while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        temp = temp + 1;
        string s = line;
        double d;
        d = stof(s.c_str());
        {
        Loop:
          if (d == number) {
            {
              x = x + 1;
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
              getline(myfile, line);
              cout << "\n"
                   << "next number is: " << line;
              string h = line;
              double z;
              z = stof(h.c_str());
              if (z <= 1.79) {
                tt = tt + 1;
                cout << " red";
              };
              if (z > 1.79) {
                cout << " blue";
                jj = jj + 1;
                if (z == d) {
                  goto Loop;
                };
              }
            }
            temp = temp + 1;
          }
        }
      }
      cout << "\n";
      cout << "\n"
           << "number repeat: " << x << t << "  red: " << tt << "  blue: " << jj
           << "   Dataset: " << temp << "\n";

      int jk = (tt * 100) / (tt + jj);
      int kl = (jj * 100) / (tt + jj);

      cout << "accur:       " << jk << "%"
           << "       " << kl << "%"
           << "\n";
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: c and c++ are two different languages, please don't tag a c++ question with a c tag

Comment: You should also explain what the problem with your attempt is.

Comment: What if the numbers in your text file are not unique? Should it get the first occurrence, or the last ocurrence, or pick one randomly?

Comment: The numbers in the file can be different and put manually numbers in text file. being unique or no not important, these numbers you see just for simple and can be any number instead and different lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. I will show you 2 different implementations.

The tricky part is always the "old" values and the "next" values. So, we must not exceed the boundaries.

In the first solution we read line by line. And the solution here is to defer the evaluation. So, we first read some lines, then make the evaluation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Try to open the file with the source data and check, if it succeeded
    if (std::ifstream file("r:\\file.txt"); file) {

        // Give instructions to the user
        std::cout << "\nWhat are you searching for?\n";

        // Get the search value from the user
        if (std::string toSearch{}; std::cin >> toSearch) {

            // Output values
            std::string previousPrevious{"*"}, previous{"*"}, current{}, next{"*"};

            // Search loop
            bool doSearch{ true };
            while (doSearch) {

                // Take care of old and new values
                previousPrevious = previous;
                previous = current;
                current = next;

                // Read value from file
                if (!std::getline(file, next)) doSearch = false;

                // And check, if we could find the searched value
                if (current == toSearch) {

                    // Show result
                    std::cout << previousPrevious << " " << previous << "   --> " << current << " <--   " << next << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Second solution is, to read the whole file into a vector and then play with the indices into the vector. This is another of the many possible solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    // Try to open the file with the source data and check, if it succeeded
    if (std::ifstream file("r:\\file.txt"); file) {

        // Give instructions to the user
        std::cout << "\nWhat are you searching for?\n";

        // Get the search value from the user
        if (std::string toSearch{}; std::cin >> toSearch) {

            // To make our life easier, we read the complete source file into a vector
            std::vector data(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file), {});

            // Now we iterate through the string and search data
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {

                // Comparison
                if (toSearch == data[i]) {
                    // Some feedback:
                    std::cout << "Found value '" << toSearch << "' at position: " << i + 1 << "\n";

                    // Check for boundaries and show result
                    if (i < data.size() - 2) std::cout << "Next value is: " << data[i + 1] << ". "; else std::cout << "No next value. ";

                    if (i > 0) {
                        std::cout << "Previous value: " << data[i - 1] << ". ";
                        if (i > 1) std::cout << "Previous previous value: " << data[i - 2] << ". "; else std::cout << "no previous previous value\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << "No previous values\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```